# Video Drivers Reinstall

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver

I was trying to fix Steam, as it was showing nothing but white in the client. I updated all the video drivers, and after I did that Steam refused to even load up, so I removed / uninstalled all my video drivers, now when I turn on my computer, it gets stuck at the "Low Graphics" warning pop-up.

How do I reinstall the video drives so Ubuntu will work again?

Comment: All the video drivers? How many do you have? How did you update them?

Comment: The process should be: 1) Find what kind of video card you have 2) Find what driver is required for it and 3) install it.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard indicates in his comment.

1) Find what kind of video card you have:

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and issue the command `sudo lshw -class video`

2) Find what driver is required for it.

There are a number of ways to do this.

a) You can run Additional Drivers and see if one comes up as Recommended and choose that.

b) You can search Google for "Ubuntu" and/or "Linux" and the  that shows up on the vendor line of your `lshw` output and/or the  that shows up on the product line of your `lshw` output.

c) You can visit the card manufacturers site as found on the aforementioned vendor line and locate Linux drivers there.

3) install it.

This process may vary.

a) If you found it in Additional Drivers, the Additional Drivers app will allow you to "Apply Changes" after driver selection.

b) If you found it via Google, you may find installation instructions there.

c) If you found it on the manufacturers site, installation instructions are normally included, either on the page where you found the driver or in a README in the driver package.

If you still have difficulty at this point you will be armed with the information you obtained going through this process which will be helpful in searching the site for an answer specific to your hardware. This information will also be useful if you don't find an answer searching and need to ask a new question. You should be asked for the output of the aforementioned command if you don't include it (including is recommended).